# Fitting Fresnel Equations Using Scipy

Tags: python, math, numpy

I am attempting a non-linear fit of Fresnel equations with data of reflectance against angle of incidence. Found on this site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations are two graphs that have a red and blue line. I need to basically fit the blue line when `n1 = 1` to my data.

Here I use the following code where `th` is theta, the angle of incidence.

```
def Rperp(th, n, norm, constant):
    numerator = np.cos(th) - np.sqrt(n**2.0 - np.sin(th)**2.0)
    denominator  = 1.0 * np.cos(th) + np.sqrt(n**2.0 - np.sin(th)**2.0)
    return ((numerator / denominator)**2.0) * norm + constant
```

The parameters I'm looking for are:

- the index of refraction n
- some normalization to multiply by and
- a constant to shift the baseline of the graph.

My attempt is the following:

```
xdata = angle[1:] * 1.0  # angle of incidence
ydata = greenDD[1:]  # reflectance
params = curve_fit(Rperp, xdata, ydata)
```

What I get is a division of zero apparently and gives me [1, 1, 1] for the parameters.  The Fresnel equation itself is the bit without the normalizer and the constant in Rperp.  Theta in the equation is the angle of incidence also.  Overall I am just not sure if I am doing this right at all to get the parameters.

The idea seems to be the first parameter in the function is the independent variable and the rest are the dependent variables going to be found.  Then you just plug into [scipy's curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and it will give you a fit to your data for the parameters.  If it is just getting around division of zero, which I had though might be integer division, then it seems like I should be set. Any help is appreciated and let me know if things need to be clarified (such as np is numpy).

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct. The error that is being generated stems from elsewhere. Is python actually giving you a traceback error? Which is it? Is it possible that the `xdata` you're passing to `curve_fit` is in degrees and not in radians?

Comment: It is in degrees. Is that would cause a problem like this?

Comment: It might. Numpy (and almost any numerical library) expects the arguments passed to the trigonometric functions, like sine, to be in radians. Not doing so could lead to unusually large variations (depending on your input data) and thus curve_fit might not find a good fit.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly my problem. I converted my graph and angle of incidence data into radians and the plot looks wonderful. Although for some reason my refraction index comes out negative I can simply inverse it.  Thanks for that tid bit of information I have been wondering why it is so screwed up for quite some time.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer and took the liberty to explain why you end up with a negative refractive index. You could accept the answer, to close the question. Good luck with the optics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to pass the arguments to the trigonometric functions, like sine, in radians, not degrees.

As for why you're getting a *negative* refractive index returned: it is because in your function, you're always squaring the refractive index. The `curve_fit` algorithm might end up in a local minimum state where (by accident) n is negative, because it has the same value as n positive. 
Ideally, you'd add constraints to the minimization problem, but for this (simple) problem, just observe your formula and remember that a result of negative n is simply solved by changing the sign, as you did. 
You could also try passing an initial guess to the algorithm and you might observe that it will not end up in the local minimum with negative value.